# I2S and PCM format

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, pcm

Can someone explain what is the difference between I2S interface and PCM interface. Does I2S interface only supports i2s format audio data and not PCM format audio data ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2s#Details

Answer (score 17):

PCM is a digital representation of an audio signal. It can be stored in memory or written on paper or whatever.  An example of a 16-bit PCM audio sample might be something like 0x0152.

I2S is a electrical serial interface used to transmit PCM data from one device to another.  The interface has a line used to delineate frames called the frame clock, a line for marking individual bits called the bit clock and 1 or more lines for the data. At the start of each frame clock a PCM sample is serialized bit by bit with a high voltage for a 1 and a zero voltage for a 0. The bit is held at that value for the entire duration of a bit clock and then it moves onto the next bit.

Here's some ascii art showing how an 8-bit sample 0x55 (01010101 binary), single channel might be transmitted. The frame clock runs at the sample rate, the bit clock at 8 times the sample rate and the data line contains the embedded data.

```
        _______________                 _
FCLK  _|               |_______________|
        _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _   _
BCLK  _| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_|
            ___     ___     ___     ___
DATA  ___0_| 1 |_0_| 1 | 0 | 1 |_0_| 1 |_
```

The wikipedia articles do a pretty good job of explaining.

Comment: PCM can describe both. The data format as you say but more importantly wire format similar to I2S.

Answer (score 4):

From NXP documentation:

**PCM**

> Most converters use a frame sync signal to signify the beginning of a
> new sample of audio data. These converters are usually associated with
> mono or single channel converters. The frame sync pulse frequency is
> usually the sample rate in the single channel converter. There are a
> few variations such as to whether the the most significant bit (MSB)
> or least significant bit (LSB) comes first or if the data starts with
> the frame sync or one bit time after. Other variations have to do with
> frame sync and clock being active high or active low. The figures
> below show some examples of audio data formats. The frame sync signal
> determines when the next audio sample is to be transferred between the
> controller and the converter. Also, the frame sync signal as seen in
> the above figure can be one bit time or a long bit time. That is why
> the frame sync frequency is usually the sample rate. There are some
> variations to accommodate more audio channels from having every other
> frame be a different channel to having the bit clock be fast enough to
> have more than one channel data in each frame sync. For example,
> having 32-bits transferred each frame sync when the data sample size
> is 16-bits. These channel variations can be interfaced to the MPC5200
> PSC, but usually stereo 2-channel converters use an I2S interface, as
> described in the next section.

**I2S**

> I2S was defined by Philips source for 2-channel stereo audio streams.
> The left or right channel audio data is defined by the state of the
> LRCK signal. The LRCK is the frame sync signal and defines the sample
> frequency for the data. I2S can accommodate any data size usually from
> 8 to 32 bits for each channel with the most significant bit (MSB)
> first. Notice the data is shifted by one bit from the start of the
> LRCLK. Since the MSB comes first, the controller can output more or
> less bits than the converter is expecting. For example, if the
> converter is 32-bit, but the controller only has 16-bit samples, the
> data can be left-justified to the MSB and have the lower 16-bits set
> 0. The converter can still accurately represent the signal in 32 bits. The same connection can be used for 8 or 32 bit data samples without
> changing anything except the number of bits used in the audio sample.
> A variation on I2S which is called left-justified swaps the state
> meaning of the frame sync signal from low meaning left to high meaning
> left, and it removes the single clock delay for the first bit in
> relation to the frame sync signal. The MPC5200 PSC can easily work
> with either format.

---

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2979.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would suggest you to edit your answer to fit the two paragraphs in block quotes and embolden the most relevant parts.